# Nodejs: parsing XML, editing values, saving the end result using sax-js module

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing, saxparser

What I'd like to achieve is:

- parsing a chunk of XML
- editing some values
- saving the end result in a
  new xml file

The module is **sax-js: https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js#readme**

The module has some built-in mechanism to read/write any.

I thought the task would be a piece of cake; on the contrary I have been struggling with it for the whole day.

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var saxStream = require("sax").createStream(true);

saxStream.on("text", function (node) {
    if (node === 'foo') { //the content I want to update
    node = 'blabla';    
  }
});
fs.createReadStream("mysongs.xml")
  .pipe(saxStream)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("mysongs-copy.xml"));
```

I did think that updating some content (see the comment above) would suffice to write the updated stream into a new file.

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks for your help,

Roland

Answer (score 1):

The [sax](http://npm.im/sax) module doesn't let you modify nodes like that. If you take a look at [this bit of code](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/lib/sax.js#L201-L205), you'll see that the input is passed indiscriminately to the output.

All hope is not, however, lost! Check out the [pretty-print example](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/examples/pretty-print.js) - it would be a good starting point for what you want to do. You'd have to do a bit of work to implement the readable part of the stream, though, if you still want to be able to `.pipe()` out of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the general structure of the XML, you can try xml-flow. It converts an XML stream into objects, but has a utility to convert them back to xml strings:
https://github.com/matthewmatician/xml-flow

Answer (score 0):

Based on deoxxa's answer I wrote an NPM module for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax-streamer